# Typescript regex exclude whole string if followed by specific string

Tags: regex, typescript, regex-negation

I'm been running into weird issues with regex and Typescript in which I'm trying to have my expression replace the value of test minus the first instance if followed by test. In other words, replace the first two lines that have test but for the third line below, replace only the second value of test.

```
[test]
[test].[db]
[test].[test]
```

Where it should look like:

```
[newvalue]
[newvalue].[db]
[test].[newvalue]
```

I've come up with lots of variations but this is the one that I thought was simple enough to solve it and regex101 can confirm this works:

```
\[(\w+)\](?!\.\[test\])
```

But when using Typescript (custom task in VSTS build), it actually replaces the values like this:

```
[newvalue]
[newvalue].[db]
[newvalue].[test]
```

**Update:** It looks like a regex like (test)(?!.test) breaks when changing the use cases removing the square brackets, which makes me think this might be somewhere in the code. Could the problem be with the index that the value is replaced at?

Some of the code in Typescript that is calling this:

```
 var filePattern = tl.getInput("filePattern", true);
 var tokenRegex = tl.getInput("tokenRegex", true);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            console.info(`Starting regex replacement in [${file}]`);

            var contents = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
            var reg = new RegExp(tokenRegex, "g");

            // loop through each match
            var match: RegExpExecArray;
            // keep a separate var for the contents so that the regex index doesn't get messed up
            // by replacing items underneath it
            var newContents = contents;
            while((match = reg.exec(contents)) !== null) {
                var vName = match[1];
                    // find the variable value in the environment
                    var vValue = tl.getVariable(vName);
                    if (typeof vValue === 'undefined') {
                        tl.warning(`Token [${vName}] does not have an environment value`);
                    } else {
                        newContents = newContents.replace(match[0], vValue);
                        console.info(`Replaced token [${vName }]`);
                    }           
                }
            }
```

Full code is for the task I'm using this with: https://github.com/colindembovsky/cols-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/ReplaceTokens/replaceTokens.ts

Comment: Does look pretty odd, can you post the actual Typescript code you're using to implement it? (though, note that for a literal dot, you need to escape it first, otherwise you'll match any character)

Comment: Updated - maybe this is related to the RegExp object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this regex is working like you are expecting:

```
\[(test)\](?!\.\[test\])
```

with a Typescript code like that

```
myString.replace(/\[(test)\](?!\.\[test\])/g, "[newvalue]");
```

Instead, the regex you are using should replace also the [db] part.

I've tried with this code:

```
class Greeter {
    myString1: string;
    myString2: string;
    myString3: string;
    greeting: string;
    constructor(str1: string, str2: string, str3: string) {
        this.myString1 = str1.replace(/\[(test)\](?!\.\[test\])/g, "[newvalue]");
        this.myString2 = str2.replace(/\[(test)\](?!\.\[test\])/g, "[newvalue]");
        this.myString3 = str3.replace(/\[(test)\](?!\.\[test\])/g, "[newvalue]");
        this.greeting = this.myString1 + "\n" + this.myString2 + "\n" + this.myString3;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, these are your replacements:\n" + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("[test]", "[test].[db]", "[test].[test]");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Online playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myString1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myString2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myString3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(str1%3A%20string%2C%20str2%3A%20string%2C%20str3%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myString1%20%3D%20str1.replace(%2F%5C%5B(test)%5C%5D(%3F!%5C.%5C%5Btest%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20%22%5Bnewvalue%5D%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myString2%20%3D%20str2.replace(%2F%5C%5B(test)%5C%5D(%3F!%5C.%5C%5Btest%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20%22%5Bnewvalue%5D%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myString3%20%3D%20str3.replace(%2F%5C%5B(test)%5C%5D(%3F!%5C.%5C%5Btest%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20%22%5Bnewvalue%5D%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20this.myString1%20%2B%20%22%5Cn%22%20%2B%20this.myString2%20%2B%20%22%5Cn%22%20%2B%20this.myString3%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20these%20are%20your%20replacements%3A%5Cn%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22%5Btest%5D%22%2C%20%22%5Btest%5D.%5Bdb%5D%22%2C%20%22%5Btest%5D.%5Btest%5D%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B).